# right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this error where everytime I execute my program, "right syntax to use near '' at line 1" error appears.

Here is the query that I am trying to execute.

```
Connection();
sql_connect.Open();

string date_start = dateTimePicker_starting.Value.ToString();
string date_to = dateTimePicker_to.Value.ToString();
string empid = textBox_empid.Text;


sql_command = new MySqlCommand("select sum(lt_min_hours) as Total_Late from tbl_late where (late_date between '" + date_start + "' and '" + date_to + "' and empid = " + empid + ";", sql_connect);
sql_reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();
```

I checked the ' , and all of it has its pair. 
Please healp. I am new to mysql.

Thank you!

Comment: no need to add `";"`

Comment: i removed it but still the error appears.

Comment: What are the values of your parameters?

Comment: You added an opening bracket. Where is the closing bracket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you missed the closing parenthesis and sql_command line will be

```
sql_command = new MySqlCommand("select sum(lt_min_hours) as Total_Late from tbl_late where (late_date between '" + date_start + "' and '" + date_to + "') and empid = " + empid + ";", sql_connect);
```

Comment: Oh yes! I didn't notice that. Thank you! It works fine now.